# Export a pixel map with each color defined

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel

I want to grab every color from an image, pixel by pixel.

I’m looking for a way to export a table or 2-dimensional array containing the color of each pixel in the image. Imagine this is a close up of a photo or drawing:

[image: example pixel map with defined colors]

(Those are the hex codes for each pixel's color; #FFFF00 is yellow, #C6E0B4 is light green, etc.)

How can I export this data from Photoshop or another tool?

Comment: What size is your image?

Comment: What do you need this for? It's pretty easy to do with javascript in a browser, but that's not really within the scope of this site. Also be aware that this quickly gets very heavy if it's a large image. 1000 x 1000 px would make a 6.7MB text file with comma separated hex codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem. Thank you to *user287001* for the idea to use a .BMP image and for confirming that there's no Photoshop feature that can extract the color data for me.

### Steps in Photoshop:

1. Open image in Photoshop. Adjust Levels, Brightness/Contrast etc. to my liking.
2. Reduce the image size to a manageable number of pixels (e.g., 100 x 100 px)
3. Reduce the total number of unique colors using Image > Mode > Indexed Color. Fiddle with this until the total number of unique colors is a manageable number (e.g., ~50)
4. Save As .BMP

### Steps in Google Colab:

1. Create a Google Colab notebook. Load the .BMP image
2. Create a pixel array that contains the data from the image (e.g., `MyPixelArray = image.imread(filepath)` where `filepath` is the location of the .BMP image in my Google Drive). This creates a three-dimensional array with dimensions of *image-height* x *image-width* x 4. (The third dimension of the array is of size 4 because it contains the color of the pixel in RGBa format—example: 255, 0, 0, 255 = bright red with full opacity.)
3. Create a for loop that displays the pixel array as a table. Use the color code from the pixel array as both the value of each cell (e.g., "255, 0, 0, 255" is printed in the cell) and as the background color of the corresponding cell.

At first, my table (a Plotly graph_objects figure) was displaying so that the rows were taller than the column widths—i.e. the cells were not square. I had to use this line of code:

`fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=0, b=0, l=0, r=0), width=s*w, height=(s*h))`

after defining the figure but before `fig.show()` to take away the left and right side margins that were squeezing my table and making the cells too tall.

Comment: There are easier ways, just dump your image into any of the available ascii formats and your done.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop and many other image editing programs can save your image in some easy to decode file format such as BMP or device independent bitmap with no compression. Still the job needs a competent programmer who can understand file format descriptions and can create a program which extracts from a BMP or other image file the RGB numbers and generates a new image file which contains the numbers in human readable text and the corresponding colors as you have wanted. There's no Photoshop ready to use function for the job.